# New firefox command line: can commands be "bookmarked"

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

Since Firefox 16 we have the new cool [developer command line](http://incompleteness.me/blog/2012/06/18/firefox-command-line/) which e.g. allows me to take a screenshot of the current page.

Now instead of pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing

```
screenshot --fullpage --clipboard
```

manually each time, it would be nice to have a bookmark that does this.

But I can't find a way how to call such a command without actually opening the commandline.

I would have hoped for some kind of special "protocol", so I could type in the URL bar something like: `commandline:screenshot` (similar to `about:config`)

Or as an alternative: is it possible to call this from JavaScript?

Comment: Hm.. this might be automatable with AutoHotkey. I'll look into it a bit later if no one else has.

Comment: If it hasn't already happened, I'm sure someone will come up with an add-on to call this function, complete with customizable hotkey support.

Answer (score 0):

There are add-ons that provide screenshot capability. For Chrome there is FireShot. You surely will find such an add-on for Firefox.

Eventually you can make screenshot of the webpage in Firefox using right mouse button - clicking on background opens a small menu in which you can save the webpage body.